# Access select option with multiple attributes via $_POST in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to extract the attributes in the options tag for a select element. The select element is dynamically loaded.

The specific form level code is as below:

```
<form name='add'>
  Age: <select name='age[]'>
    <option value='1' stud_name='sre' st_address='address1'>23</option>
    <option value='2' stud_name='sam' st_address='address2'>24</option>
    <option value='5' stud_name='john' st_address='address13'>25</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

In my PHP file, I access the submitted data via: `$_POST['age'];` How can I get the other attributes and their value?

Comment: only value will be posted

Comment: you'll need to use javascript, tis can be done easily with jquery

Comment: but really, you shouldn't need to.

Comment: why did you code it like that, any good reason?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create individual input fields and control their value by Javascript while `select` is changed.

But if you persist to pass a multiple values by a single `select`, you may consider to use `json`, here an example:

HTML:

```
<form name="add">
  Age:
  <select name="age">
    <option value='{"age":"1","stud_name":"sre","st_address":"address1"}'>23</option>
    <option value='{"age":"2","stud_name":"sam","st_address":"address2"}'>24</option>
    <option value='{"age":"5","stud_name":"john","st_address":"address13"}'>25</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

  $age = json_decode($_POST['age']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't access attribute values in php. only you can access is post data. If you want to access attributes in php, you have to use javascript or jQuery.

ex : 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_attr_set

same as above you can set values to post in a hidden field and submit to php

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the form's attribute; method="post" in order to use $_POST in php. Like: `<form method="post" name="add"> ... </form>`